# Avoiding Question Flagged as Duplicate when Couldn't Find Question in Search

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, asking-questions

I've recently been flagged for a question and it was marked as duplicate.  How do I not get flagged for duplicate questions when I searched for a similar question but the search did not result in the questions and answers that I was looking for?

Comment: Closed as duplicate. Oh the irony...

Comment: But in all honesty, if you couldn't find the original, don't worry about it at all. Your post will help serve as a signpost to the *next* person who uses the same terms you used!